# authenticate_with_http_token evaluates to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, http-token-authentication

I'm trying to create a very basic authenticator but unfortunately I'm getting nil in return causing my route to 401 since its unauthorized.

```
[20] pry(#<API::UsersController>)> 
ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods.authenticate_with_http_token
NoMethodError: undefined method `authenticate_with_http_token' for     
ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods:Module

[22] pry(#<API::UsersController>)> cd    
ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods

[23] pry(#<Module>):1> ls
ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods#methods:
authenticate_or_request_with_http_token  authenticate_with_http_token      
request_http_token_authentication
locals: _  __  _dir_  _ex_  _file_  _in_  _out_  _pry_

[24] pry(#<Module>):1>
```

Code:

```
protected
  def authenticate
    authenticate_token || render_unauthorized
  end

  def authenticate_token
    binding.pry
    authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
      User.find_by(auth_token: token)
    end
  end

  def render_unauthorized
    self.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Token realm="Application"'
    render json: 'Bad credentials', status: 401
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like your `API::UsersController` (or alternatively your `ApplicationController`) needs:

```
include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods
```